# Removing dynamically added row from a table using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

My code adds a row to table when a plus is pressed, and it adds it with the right references so when I submit my form data I know what data is what.  The minus I am having a bit difficulty getting it to work in removing the row just added or another row previously added from the table.

I thought maybe its my .bind in that last line of the addRow function as I saw here it might should be a .on ?

[Issue while removing a dynamically added row from a html table using jquery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17672496/issue-while-removing-a-dynamically-added-row-from-a-html-table-using-jquery)

In either case my code is here:

```
   <script language='javascript' type='text/javascript'>

        $(document).ready(function () {

            function addRow() {
                var $myTable = $("#myTable").find('tbody');
                var parent = $(this).parent("td").parent("tr").attr("id");
                var newRowID = $myTable.children("tr").length + 1;

                var $newRow = $("<tr id='regFacEmpType" + newRowID + "' data-parent-row='" + parent + "'>");
                $newRow.append($("<td align='center'>611000</td>"));
                $newRow.append($("<td class='style1'><input type='text' name='RegEmpType" + newRowID + "' size='15' data-emp-type='Regular' /></td>"));
                //see the data-emp-type not sure how else to know what is coming back unless name is going to be dynamically generated here using  a counter.  Should
                //only be one type of each field, so instead of EmpType being generic:  EmpTypeRegular1 and if they add another employee then EmpTypeRegular2 etc.

                $newRow.append($("<td><input type='checkbox' name='RegEmpIDC" + newRowID + "' value='true' /></td>"));
                $newRow.append($("<td align='center' id='RegEmpAgencyBudgt" + newRowID + "'>$43,0000</td>"));
                $newRow.append($("<td align='center' id='RegEmpRowBdgt" + newRowID + "'>$3,0000</td>"));
                $newRow.append($("<td class='style1' id='RegEmpRowAdjBudget" + newRowID + "'><input type='text' name='AdjustedBudgetRegularEmpType" + newRowID + "' /></td>"));
                $newRow.append($("<td class='style1' id='RegEmpRowComments" + newRowID + "'><input type='text' name='RegEmpComments" + newRowID + "' /></td>"));
                $newRow.append($("<td></td>").append($("<button class='addRegular' type='button'>+</button>").bind("click", addRow))); //make it where any plus subsequently added will add a row
                $newRow.append($("<td></td>").append($("<button class='removeRegular' id='removeRegular" + newRowID +"' type='button'>-</button>").bind("click", removeRegularRow(newRowID))));
                $myTable.append($newRow);
            };


            //for some reason this is called everytime I click the PLUS also it does nothing?
            function removeRegularRow(index) {
                        $("#regFacEmpType" + index).remove();
            };



            $(".addRegular").on("click", addRow); //make it so the default row adds a new one.
        });
</script>
</head>
<body>
    <FORM action="" method="post">

    <table id='myTable'>

            <tbody>
                <tr id="FacultyEmployees">
                    <th align="center" class="style1">Index Number</th>
                    <th align="center" class="style1">Faculty Type</th>
                    <th align="center" class="style1">IDC</th>
                    <th align="center" class="style1">Agency Budgeted Amount</th>
                    <th align="center" class="style1">PI Budgeted Amount</th>
                    <th align="center" class="style1">PI Adjusted Budget</th>
                    <th align="center" class="style1">Comments</th>
                </tr>
                <tr id="regFacEmpType1" data-child-type='regExemptEmpType1' data-parent-type='regFacEmpType1'>
                    <!-- next row would be regExemptEmpType1 etc -->
                    <td align="center">611000</td>
                    <td align="center">Regular</td>
                    <td><input type="checkbox" name="IDC" value="true" /></td>
                    <td align="center" id="agencyBudgeted1">$43,0000</td>
                    <td align="center" id="piBudgetedAmount1">$33,0000</td>
                    <td id="piAdjustedBudget1"><input type="text" name="PI Adjusted Budget" width="5" /></td>
                    <td class="style1"><input type="text" name="Comments" id="comments1" size="15" /></td>
                    <td><button type='button' class="addRegular">+</button></td>                    
                </tr>
            </tbody>

        </table>
        <button type="submit"/> Submit </button>
        </FORM>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Solving the issue

Concerning your JavaScript code:

- Remove the `bind()` function;
- Remove the `removeRegularRow()` function;
- Add the following `on('click'..` event inside `$(document).ready`:

  ```
  $("#myTable").on('click', '.removeRegular', function(){

      $(this).parent().parent().remove();
      // It's faster with: $(this).closest('tr').remove();

  });
  ```

### On why this solves the issue at hand

The problem is that this row of elements is dynamically inserted and only after the DOM had everything loaded and was [ready](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12637725/1494516). In a simple way, **your algorithm won't find the desired HTML inserted everything was loaded**.

With `$('.some_parent_element').on('click', '.element_desired', function(){...});` you can circumvent this problem and do whatever you want with the element. That is, let's stick with the idea of *suitable for all ages*, shall we? :P

The [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17672496/1494516) you mentioned has a very good and concise explanation. Try to understand that answer because you will need to understand for future coding.

### On why it's faster with `closest`

Well, we [have a great answer here in SO](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8789362/1494516) explaining the "why" so I will link to it. But, **to sum it up, it revolves around searching the entire document or an specific area of the document**. There is also the library layers that needs to be dealt with to finally get where you want. As an addendum, check this [performance test](https://jsperf.com/jquery-closest-faster-than-parents/2).

The *docs* says:

> `parent()` *gets the parent of each element in the current set of matched elements, optionally filtered by a selector*.
>
> `closest()` *For each element in the set, get the first element that matches the selector by testing the element itself and traversing up through its ancestors in the DOM tree*.

There are ways to do it faster than `parent()` and `closest()` that relies on 'native' Java Script. But you should always take into account readability as well as *bosses and clients stubbornness*...

Also take into account your application's target audience. Scalability is important, of course, but even if something is slower than some other, if you application is not huge or doesn't have a lot of data to deal with, it won't really matter what you use. Just make sure to avail it properly and constantly to change whenever needed.

### Testing the rewritten code

You can verify that the code, with the changes, now works. Just click on the button "Run code snippet" down below.

```js
$(document).ready(function () {

      var index;
    
            function addRow() {
                var $myTable = $("#myTable").find('tbody');
                var parent = $(this).parent("td").parent("tr").attr("id");
                var newRowID = $myTable.children("tr").length + 1;
                
                index = newRowID;

                var $newRow = $("<tr id='regFacEmpType" + newRowID + "' data-parent-row='" + parent + "'>");
                $newRow.append($("<td align='center'>611000</td>"));
                $newRow.append($("<td class='style1'><input type='text' name='RegEmpType" + newRowID + "' size='15' data-emp-type='Regular' /></td>"));
                //see the data-emp-type not sure how else to know what is coming back unless name is going to be dynamically generated here using  a counter.  Should
                //only be one type of each field, so instead of EmpType being generic:  EmpTypeRegular1 and if they add another employee then EmpTypeRegular2 etc.

                $newRow.append($("<td><input type='checkbox' name='RegEmpIDC" + newRowID + "' value='true' /></td>"));
                $newRow.append($("<td align='center' id='RegEmpAgencyBudgt" + newRowID + "'>$43,0000</td>"));
                $newRow.append($("<td align='center' id='RegEmpRowBdgt" + newRowID + "'>$3,0000</td>"));
                $newRow.append($("<td class='style1' id='RegEmpRowAdjBudget" + newRowID + "'><input type='text' name='AdjustedBudgetRegularEmpType" + newRowID + "' /></td>"));
                $newRow.append($("<td class='style1' id='RegEmpRowComments" + newRowID + "'><input type='text' name='RegEmpComments" + newRowID + "' /></td>"));
                $newRow.append($("<td></td>").append($("<button class='addRegular' type='button'>+</button>").bind("click", addRow))); //make it where any plus subsequently added will add a row
                $newRow.append($("<td></td>").append($("<button class='removeRegular' id='removeRegular" + newRowID +"' type='button'>-</button>")));
                $myTable.append($newRow);
            };

      $("#myTable").on('click', '.removeRegular', function(){
                
             $(this).parent().parent().remove();
            
            });


            $(".addRegular").on("click", addRow); //make it so the default row adds a new one.
        });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<FORM action="" method="post">

    <table id='myTable'>

            <tbody>
                <tr id="FacultyEmployees">
                    <th align="center" class="style1">Index Number</th>
                    <th align="center" class="style1">Faculty Type</th>
                    <th align="center" class="style1">IDC</th>
                    <th align="center" class="style1">Agency Budgeted Amount</th>
                    <th align="center" class="style1">PI Budgeted Amount</th>
                    <th align="center" class="style1">PI Adjusted Budget</th>
                    <th align="center" class="style1">Comments</th>
                </tr>
                <tr id="regFacEmpType1" data-child-type='regExemptEmpType1' data-parent-type='regFacEmpType1'>
                    <!-- next row would be regExemptEmpType1 etc -->
                    <td align="center">611000</td>
                    <td align="center">Regular</td>
                    <td><input type="checkbox" name="IDC" value="true" /></td>
                    <td align="center" id="agencyBudgeted1">$43,0000</td>
                    <td align="center" id="piBudgetedAmount1">$33,0000</td>
                    <td id="piAdjustedBudget1"><input type="text" name="PI Adjusted Budget" width="5" /></td>
                    <td class="style1"><input type="text" name="Comments" id="comments1" size="15" /></td>
                    <td><button type='button' class="addRegular">+</button></td>                    
                </tr>
            </tbody>

        </table>
        <button type="submit"/> Submit </button>
        </FORM>
```

Comment: so many great answers not sure who to mark as answered.  I like this cause of the why portion.  Starting to get back into Jquery and not simple stuff so this was a good bit on it.    I am curious what you meant with the comment its faster with $(this).closest, why not use that if it is faster/better what was the reasoning?

Comment: Well, that is simply because, in fact, about two weeks ago an intern where I work had the very same problem and thought that `parent()` made more sense to him. So I used it and commented the other.
Also, `parent()` is very direct. Won't be the case with a table but if you, for some reason see wrongly what is the `closest()`, you get a code that doesn't work and maybe will take a few minutes until you figure it out. It really depends on case but `closest()` is faster. But watch out for new elements.
Also, a [test](http://goo.gl/EzrC7x) that profs it is faster.

Comment: But [there is a great SO question/answer about it](http://goo.gl/kjR8Su). There are ways that are faster. But it takes aways the 'structure' / 'beauty' of your code because doesn't rely only in jQuery but native Java Script - well, I can't use those because my boss strictly says no. Why? Because his clients says no. Why? Exactly because of that 'beauty' in code (readability). So if you can, use the fastest way!! :)

Answer (score 4):

When you get into multiple repeating elements in a page using ID to target elements is the least preferred approach.

It gets far more complicated trying to make ID's match and it is much simpler to make traverses based on classes and structure of repeating elements.

Also one handler can manage all repeating elements. The following can be placed anywhere in the code base ... once per page load

```
$(document).on('click','.removeRegular', function(){
     $(this).closest('tr').remove();  
});
```

Then on the `tr` you can add a database identifier that can be used for ajax requests

```
<tr data-id="serverIdValue">
```

And upgrade the handler:

```
$(document).on('click','.removeRegular', function(){
     var $row = $(this).closest('tr'), rowId = $row.data('id');
     // only remove once server update confirmed
     $.post('/api/row/delete', {id: rowId}, function(response){
          // validate response first then remove the row
          $row.remove();
     });          
});
```

Note the separation of concerns...no inline code required and no need to process this in any sort of loop

Comment: Ty for the bit on handling the ajax side!   I will need to do this not with the level of granularity but I will def need to do this.

Answer (score 2):

bind your click event like so:-

```
$newRow.append($("<td></td>").append($("<button class='removeRegular' id='removeRegular" + newRowID +"' type='button'>-</button>").bind("click", function(){ removeRegularRow(newRowID); })));
```

[**Fiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/Lvapm7ge/)

Answer (score 2):

This line:

```
.bind("click", removeRegularRow(newRowID))
```

This is actually calling the `removeRegularRow()` function and expecting a `function` to get returned.

You can change it by wrapping it inside an anonymous function:

```
.bind("click", function() { removeRegularRow(newRowID) })
```

Answer (score 2):

A couple of things.  First, `.bind()` is no longer the preferred method of adding handlers.  As of jQuery 1.7, `.on()` is the best method to use.  Secondly, in this code:

```
.bind("click", removeRegularRow(newRowID))
```

You are actually calling `removeRegularRow` at the time you attach the handler, and attaching the return value to the click event.  This is obviously not what you want.  You want to pass a function reference:

```
.on("click", function(){ removeRegularRow(newRowID); } ))
```

Even better however, is to attach a single handler, using the table itself as the delegate and filtering on the `removeRegular` button class:

```
$('#myTable').on('click', '.removeRegular', function() {
    $(this).parent().closest('tr').remove();
});
```

This uses a single handler, and because it is attached to the table, instead of the row, you don't have to worry about what happens when elements are added and removed (as long as the table always exists).  You also don't have to worry about tracking ID's and counting rows, etc, because the button simply looks at the ancestor that is the table row and removes it.  Much simpler.

Answer (score 0):

On this line

```
$newRow.append($("<td></td>").append($("<button class='removeRegular' id='removeRegular" + newRowID +"' type='button'>-</button>").bind("click", removeRegularRow(newRowID))));
```

You are triggering the function in this code `.bind("click", removeRegularRow(newRowID))` this means that you are calling the function instead of assign him as handler.